# Binding к this[enum] свойству экземпляра класса

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Есть `enum`

```
namespace namespace1.namespace2{
  enum PropertyObject 
  {
    A=1,
    B=2,
    ...
  }
}
```

и класс совершенно в другом `namespace`

```
public class MyClass
{
  public Object this[namespace1.namespace2.PropertyObject property]
  {
    get
    {
      return ...;
    }
  }
}
```

Список экземпляров всунут в `ItemsSource` `ListView`, есть также `DataTemplate` забитый как `ItemTemplate` у `ListView`

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=this[namespace1.namespace2.PropertyObject.A]}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

я уверен, что данный `PropertyObject` у экземпяров установлен, однако пишет, что не может достучаться до этого свойства, как создать валидный `Binding` к этим свойствам?

ошибка: *System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '[]' property not found on 'object' ''MyClass' (HashCode=55693485)'. BindingExpression:Path=this[namespace1.namespace2.PropertyObject.A]; DataItem='MyClass' (HashCode=55693485); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')*

Comment: вы уверены, что с `this` валидный синтаксис?

Comment: Да вот не уверен, а как правильно не знаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете неверный синтаксис для получения значения перечисления. В рамках XAML пространства имён в сборках (namespace в C#) и пространства имён в XML (xmlns в XML) задаются в шапке файла. При этом даже указание точного типа может не понадобиться: XAML достаточно умный, чтобы приобразовать строку к перечислению самостоятельно.

Понятия "this" в биндингах тоже нет. Скорее всего, вам нужен или текущий контекст (`Path='.'` или просто `Path=''`), или текущий элемент (`RelativeSource='{RelativeSource Self}'` и прочие).

Положим, у нас есть следующий код:

```
namespace HakunaMatata
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new Model();
        }
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public string this [Other.Property prop] => prop.ToString() + " from Indexer";
    }
}

namespace Other
{
    public enum Property
    {
        Foo,
        Bar,
    }
}
```

Тогда все из способов обращения к индексатору будут работать корректно:

```
<Window x:Class="HakunaMatata.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HakunaMatata"
        xmlns:other="clr-namespace:Other">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=[Foo]}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=[(other:Property)Foo]}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.[Foo]}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.[(other:Property)Foo]}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: спасибо, завтра проверю. Сегодня не имею возможности.

Comment: Заработало, как `{Binding Path=[A].AnyProperty, StringFormat=' ({0})'}`

Answer (score 1):

[Синтаксис Binding.Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms752300(v=vs.100).aspx#Path_Syntax) - есть примеры разных привязок.

Comment: Ссылки меют свойство умирать. Включите в ответ нужную информацию по ссылке.

Comment: Думаю, что с MSDN ссылка не умрёт...